# Wrong result from the conversion in an array

Tags: c, arrays

Let's say that I have

```
char number[2] = "2";
```

In my code I get number 2 as a string that's why i have char. Now with the usage of atoi I convert this char to int

```
int conv_number;
conv_number = atoi(number);
printf("Result : %d\n", conv_number);
```

which returns me Result : 2. Now I want to put this value in an array and print the result of the array.So I wrote

```
int array[] = {conv_number};
printf("%d\n",array);
```

Unfortunately my result is not 2 but -1096772864. What am I missing;

Comment: `array` is the address of the array.

Comment: `array` is  not actually an address of the array, rather decays to a pointer to the first element in the array which is equal to the address of the array. Pls correct if am wrong

Comment: This: `int array[] = {conv_number};' also makes a one-element array, which isn't very useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing that your `array` is `int[]` not `int`, which is the expected second argument for `printf` when you use the digit format parameter `%d`.

Use `printf("%d\n",array[0])` instead, since you want to access the first value in your array.

#### Further explanation

In this circumstances `array` in your `printf` expression behaves as `int*`. You would get the same result if you were to use `printf("%d\n",&array[0])`, aka the address of the first element. Note that if you're really interested in the address use the `%p` format specifier instead.

Answer (score 2):

in the expression `printf("%d\n",array);`, array is an array (obviously) of int, which is similar to an `int*`.
the value of `array` is not the value of the first cell (eg. array[0]) but decays to the array's address.

If you run your code multiple times, you'll probably have different values (the array location will vary from one run to an other)

You have to write : `printf("%d\n",array[0]);`
which is equivalent to `printf("%d\n",*array);`

Answer (score 1):

You are printing base address of your array. Instead of that you need to print value at that array address. like,

```
printf("%d",array[0]);
```

Comment: Actually printing the address should done with `%p` and not `%d`.